# Given a date with timezone set, get the timezone offset in hours

Tags: sql, t-sql

There is a table containing datetime with specified timezone, for example `2015-03-29 03:01:00 +02:00`. For every record, I need a query to get this `+2` as integer.

Comment: Not all timezones adjust in whole hours.  So if the adjustment was 30 minutes, what value are you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

If that's an actual DateTimeOffset column, and not a string, this should work:

```
SELECT DATEPART(tz, DateTimeOffsetColumn)/60
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work too :

```
select convert(int,  replace(right(column_name , 4), ':00', '' ))  [offset]
```

Result: 2